# CSS postion question from a newbie out of curiousity

Tags: html, css

just started learning how to create websites seriously for a few weeks.
I am taking a online course right now too.
And, I was wondering about the markup & styling below.
(Below markup&styling is a example.)
(This example code is based on the course content.)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  /* background-color: black; */
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /* background-color: aqua; */
}
```

```html
<section class="section-1">
  <div class="section-wrapper section-1-wrapper">
    <div class="section-1-heading-wrapper">
      <h1 class="section-1-heading-i">
        Example Text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I was wondering why do someone need this styling? Seemed like a duplicate styling to my eyes, so I thought that I could use some help with this :)
If anyone got the time, pray tell.

Comment: This CSS is useless for this HTML. The `.section` class and the `.wrapper` class are not present in the HTML.

Comment: as @FS-GSW said. Anyway the essence of your question should be the somewhat similarity of properties and values used. Well to tell you they are not redundant. You can learn more on `CSS units` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp) and `positions` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: My bad! I mistakingly uploaded incomplete HTML!
Thank you for answering my question too :)

Below are correct markup:

<div class="wrapper">
        <section class="section-1">
          <div class="section-wrapper section-1-wrapper">
            <div class="section-1-heading-wrapper">
              <h1 class="section-1-heading">The best wines around the worlds</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
</div>

Comment: And CSS:


.wrapper{
         width: 100vw;
         height: 100vh;
         position: relative;
      /* background-color: black; */
}

section{
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
      /* background-color: aqua; */
}

And @Yong Thank you for the URL

Answer (score 0):

Position statements are very useful for styling web pages. There are a few types of this: positon: relative, position: fixed, position: sticky and position: absolute. We can use z-index property of css ONLY with the elements which styled with position statement. So keep going. It is very important property.

Comment: Hi, Asilbek
Thank you so much for your comment :)
I will surely march on. Been way too long since I have decided to postpone learning these things, so.

Will look into MDN doc guides and other resources to make sense out of this!

All the best to you, and thank you again